# Weighted MaxSMT Z3

Tags: z3

I was going through the Z3 (Objective functions) tutorial and came across the following example:

```
(declare-const a Bool)
(declare-const b Bool)
(declare-const c Bool)
(assert-soft a :weight 1 :id A)
(assert-soft b :weight 2 :id B)
(assert-soft c :weight 3 :id A)
(assert (= a c))
(assert (not (and a b)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I don't understand Z3's output:

```
A |-> 0 
   B |-> 2 
   sat 
   (model (define-fun c () Bool true) 
   (define-fun b () Bool false) 
   (define-fun a () Bool true) )
```

My understanding is that Weighted MaxSMT tries to maximize weighted sum of boolean expressions. Therefore, are we supposed to get A |->4 and B|->0 since both a and c are true and b is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `assert-soft` call, the weights are "penalty" values you are willing to accrue if you were to choose not to satisfy that goal. So, in this assignment, Z3 is picking `a` and `c` as `true`, hence satisfying the first and the third `assert-soft` constraints, thus taking no penalty for them. This means `A |-> 0`, since all soft constraints in this group are satisfied.

Of course, to make the problem `sat`, picking `a` and `c` to be `true` requires `b` to be `false`, and hence you accrue a penalty of `2` for that failed constraint group.

Note that z3 has to satisfy all regular `assert` constraints. In addition to that, it tries to satisfy as "many" of the `assert-soft` constraints as possible, minimizing the penalty accrued for those that are not satisfied.

This [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a938/cdcf32f340fd654aa2e9d372f3eff9fabb62.pdf?_ga=2.15411188.334716402.1498509209-728137339.1498509209) has an excellent description of Z3's optimization features.